# Reference a virtual location as include path in GCC

Tags: c, azure, gcc, stm32cubeide

I am trying to add Azure ADU in my project and maintain external source code hierarchy intact(as they are added as submodules).

My problem lies in a couple of source files having include directives referencing a header file with an added relative path that does not exist.

For example, the file [adu_core_interface.h](https://github.com/Azure/iot-hub-device-update/blob/2cd165ba05cf7a6eff34cbf6c26e4ae30cc9d5d9/src/agent/adu_core_interface/inc/aduc/adu_core_interface.h#L16) contains the include directive  `#include <azureiot/iothub_client_core_common.h>` which resides in [another repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/main/iothub_client/inc/iothub_client_core_common.h) but is not located in a subfolder named `azureiot` inside that repo.

Obviously, simply adding the path to [iothub_client_core_common.h](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/main/iothub_client/inc/iothub_client_core_common.h) as an include path (which would be `-Iazure-iot-sdk-c/blob/main/iothub_client/inc/`) will not work.
I cannot include the file directly as well (using `-include` switch in GCC) as the #include directive in [adu_core_interface.h](https://github.com/Azure/iot-hub-device-update/blob/2cd165ba05cf7a6eff34cbf6c26e4ae30cc9d5d9/src/agent/adu_core_interface/inc/aduc/adu_core_interface.h#L16) references a subfolder that doesn't exist.

My question is, is there a way to have [iothub_client_core_common.h](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/main/iothub_client/inc/iothub_client_core_common.h) passed as an include so that GCC sees its relative location as `azureiot/iothub_client_core_common.h` when compiling?

The project is managed and built using STM32CubeIDE.

Answer (score 0):

In my specific case, I should've just read the doc more thoroughly and use the `install_deps.sh` script.